# Is there a way to turn on follow logs and auto-refresh as the default for minikube?

Tags: logging, minikube

I find that when I go to look at minikube logs I tend to want them to both follow and refresh nearly 100% of the time.  Instead of having to toggle these on every time, is there a way to configure minikube to run with auto-refresh and sync on by default when viewing logs?

Answer (score 0):

The is a tool - [SolarWinds®  Papertrail™](https://www.solarwinds.com/papertrail). It is a cloud-hosted log management solution that lets you live tail your logs from a central location. Using Papertrail, you can view real-time log events from your entire Kubernetes cluster in a single browser window.

Take a look: [live-tail-kubernetes-logs](https://www.papertrail.com/blog/how-to-live-tail-kubernetes-logs/), [configuring-centralized-logging-from-kubernetes](https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-centralized-logging-from-kubernetes/).